# Notifying listeners from deep within model when using Flutter scoped model

Tags: mvvm, model, dart, flutter

I have a dynamically built list of checkboxes that each correspond to a member variable in my model:

```
Checkbox(
    value: pointProtocolRecord.checkResult == 1,
    onChanged: (value){
        pointProtocolRecord.checkResult = value ? 1 : 0;
    }
),
```

However, calling `notifyListeners()` to actually update the checkboxes is not straightforward since `pointProtocolRecord` is an object nested deep within the model:

```
ChecklistPointProtocolRecord pointProtocolRecord = 
    model
        .activeChecklistProtocol
        .controlPoints
        .singleWhere((k) => k.checklistPointGuid == record.checklistPointGuid);
```

Simply adding `notifyListeners()` in the `onChanged` handler works fine:

```
Checkbox(
    value: pointProtocolRecord.checkResult == 1,
    onChanged: (value){
        pointProtocolRecord.checkResult = value ? 1 : 0;
        model.notifyListeners();
    }
),
```

but IntelliJ underlines the call and gives a hint that says

> The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart'

Is there any danger calling `notifyListeners()` from outside the Model?

I guess I could add a method to the model that only calls `notifyListeners()`, but is that a good solution? Are there better ways of updating the models listeners from deep within the models member hierarchy?